# Can't get ref.current.offsetWidth

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I've trying to make contextMenu.

I want to get offsetWidth and offsetHeight from ref.current, but console.log prints undefined.

```js
const ContextMenu: React.FC<ContextMenuProps> = props => {
  const thisComponent = useRef(null);
  const [isVisible, setIsVisible] = useState<boolean>(false);
  let thisComponentHeight = null;
  let thisComponentWidth = null;

  useEffect(() => {
    document.addEventListener("contextmenu", contextMenuHandler);
    if (thisComponent && thisComponent.current) {
      thisComponentWidth = thisComponent.current;
      thisComponentHeight = thisComponent.current;
      console.log(thisComponent.current)
    }
  }, []);

  return (
    <Column ref={thisComponent}>
      <div>test</div>
      <div>test2</div>
    </Column>
  );
};

export default ContextMenu;
```

This is the picture of `console.log(thisComponent.current);`

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That `Column` component looks like it belongs to another library, not something native to React, so they might have defined their own set of properties in the `current` object. Just wrap the `Column` in a `div` or `span`, then give that markup the `ref`. you will be able to get the `offsetWidth` as well as the native DOM properties.

```
  return (
    <div ref={thisComponent}>
      <Column>
        <div>test</div>
        <div>test2</div>
      </Column>
    </div>
  );
```